# Phoenix test data is persisting making the tests non-repeatable

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Please note that this is a duplicate of [my forum post](https://elixirforum.com/t/test-data-is-persisting-making-the-tests-non-repeatable/3285).

I'm using Phoenix (1.2.1) and having trouble in my test environment. The problem is that the data being inserted (updated, deleted, etc) across tests are being persisted in the test database making my testing non-repeatable.

First Run:

```
root@d7594ec7baf0:/mnt/sidecar_api# mix test
................................
Finished in 2.2 seconds

32 tests, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 180820
```

Second Run:

```
root@d7594ec7baf0:/mnt/sidecar_api# mix test
...........................

  1) test user signup with POST /v1/users with valid attributes   (SidecarApi.V1.UserControllerTest)
 test/controllers/v1/user_controller_test.exs:15
 Assertion with == failed
 code: response == expected
 lhs:  %{"jsonapi" => %{"version" => "1.0"}, "data" => %{"attributes" => %{"first-name" => "Juan", "last-name" => "Dela Cruz", "primary-email" => "jdelacruz@example.com", "primary-mobile-number" => "639123456789", "username" => "jdelacruz"}, "type" => "user", "id" => "2"}}
 rhs:  %{"jsonapi" => %{"version" => "1.0"}, "data" => %{"attributes" => %{"first-name" => "Juan", "last-name" => "Dela Cruz", "primary-email" => "jdelacruz@example.com", "primary-mobile-number" => "639123456789", "username" => "jdelacruz"}, "type" => "user", "id" => "1"}}
 stacktrace:
   test/controllers/v1/user_controller_test.exs:36: (test)

....

Finished in 2.3 seconds
32 tests, 1 failure

Randomized with seed 556822
```

The only relevant info in these instances is the object ID. I'm checking if the inserted record has the ID 1 which is my assumption on the state of the DB before the execution of all my tests.

Here's my `test.exs`:

```
use Mix.Config

config :sidecar_api, SidecarApi.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4001],
  server: false

config :logger, level: :warn

config :sidecar_api, SidecarApi.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "sidecar",
  password: "sidecardb",
  database: "sidecar_test",
  hostname: "sidecar-db-main",
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox
```

and `test_helper.exs`

```
ExUnit.start

Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(SidecarApi.Repo, :manual)
```

Note that after each tests, checking the content of postgres from `psql` itself is reflecting empty databases. Both for development and testing environments. Right now, I'm confused where to look at.

```
sidecar_dev=# select * from users;
 id | username | password | first_name | last_name | inserted_at |     updated_at
----+----------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------
(0 rows)


sidecar_test=# select * from users;
 id | username | password | first_name | last_name | inserted_at | updated_at
----+----------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure this isn't because your tests are being run in a different order each time?

Comment: Can you attach more important snippets - your tests etc. If you run tests for side-effect functions do you remember to not use them asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the data is being cleared between runs, but your id sequence is not being reset.

> ```
> code: response == expected
>   lhs:  %{"jsonapi" => %{"version" => "1.0"}, "data" => %{"attributes" => %{"first-name" => "Juan", "last-name" => "Dela Cruz", "primary-email" => "jdelacruz@example.com", "primary-mobile-number" => "639123456789", "username" => "jdelacruz"}, "type" => "user", "id" => "2"}}
>   rhs:  %{"jsonapi" => %{"version" => "1.0"}, "data" => %{"attributes" => %{"first-name" => "Juan", "last-name" => "Dela Cruz", "primary-email" => "jdelacruz@example.com", "primary-mobile-number" => "639123456789", "username" => "jdelacruz"}, "type" => "user", "id" => "1"}}
> ```

Note that the ID is different